# Cause a mac to crash on purpose

Tags: macos

Strange question but is there a way of causing a mac to crash?

I need to simulate a worst case scenario and check a redundancy set up.

Thanks

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "crash", and what permissions you have. In general, with root, it's trivial; without root, it's... well, still pretty easy if a fork bomb counts.

Comment: That said, I don't see how this is a software development question as such.

Comment: We are developing software and want to test the redundancy switching over. Yeah just got told about a fork bomb will try that. Thanks

Comment: If you want to test failover, you should be thinking about specific failure modes. What if a system is still up but loses network? What if your two systems can't communicate with each other, but can communicate with the outside world? Just simulating some completely random crash isn't even *remotely* adequate to modeling the space you need to test.

Comment: (...and just because it's done in the service of software development doesn't make it a software development question; a better criteria is whether something is a tool or practice specific to or principally encountered during the course of software development).

Comment: ...getting back to testing failover -- if you're serious about what you're doing, you'll have network-controlled power supplies; if you have something like a shared block device where multiple concurrent write attempts can cause data corruption, something like that is mandatory as a STONITH mechanism ("Shoot The Other Node In The Head") anyhow.

Comment: ...so, if what you want to test is a system becoming suddenly and completely unavailable, you just tell the NPS to kill it, and there you are. But the places where failover systems *actually fail* (and thus the cases you need to test) are typically a lot more interesting than that, calling for watchdogs, healthchecks, and the like.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I will look into it further. From what I understand the problem they are having is the music program that the program is interfacing is using to many resources on the MAC (Apparently it is older and keeps freezing). But like I said I will look further into it. Thanks for you help!